# AES-256 mix column code generating output bigger than 8 bits

Tags: encryption, aes, key-size

I'm implementing AES-256 in JavaScript with block size 128 bits and I understand every thing about AES except `MixColumn` transformation.

So I copied this code from the internet and both `MixColumn` and `InvMixColumn` transformation works perfectly against each other but the problem is the `MixColumn` code is generating bytes in the block bigger than 8 bits which is not being accepted by the other functions like `SubBytes` etc.

```
AES.prototype.TEMPMixColumns = function(state)
{
  var i, Tmp, Tm, t;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  {  
    t   = state[i*4];
    Tmp = state[i*4] ^ state[i*4+1] ^ state[i*4+2] ^ state[i*4+3] ;
    Tm  = state[i*4] ^ state[i*4+1]  ;
    Tm = this.xtime(Tm);  
    state[i*4+0] ^= Tm ^ Tmp ;
    Tm  = state[i*4+1] ^ state[i*4+2] ; Tm = this.xtime(Tm);  state[i*4+1]     ^= Tm ^ Tmp ;
    Tm  = state[i*4+2] ^ state[i*4+3] ; Tm = this.xtime(Tm);  state[i*4+2] ^= Tm ^ Tmp ;
    Tm  = state[i*4+3] ^ t ;              Tm = this.xtime(Tm);  state[i*4+3] ^= Tm ^ Tmp ;


  }
  return state
}

AES.prototype.xtime = function(x){ 
    return ((x << 1) ^ (((x >> 7) & 1) * 0x1b)) 
}

AES.prototype.Multiply = function(x, y){
    var t =  (((y & 1) * x) ^ ((y >> 1 & 1) * this.xtime(x)) ^ ((y >> 2 & 1) * this.xtime(this.xtime(x))) ^ ((y >> 3 & 1) * this.xtime(this.xtime(this.xtime(x)))) ^ ((y >> 4 & 1) * this.xtime(this.xtime(this.xtime(this.xtime(x))))));
    return t;
}

AES.prototype.TEMPInvMixColumns = function( state)
{
  var i, a, b, c, d;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  { 
a = state[i*4+0];
b = state[i*4+1];
c = state[i*4+2];
d = state[i*4+3];

state[i*4+0] = this.Multiply(a, 0x0e) ^ this.Multiply(b, 0x0b) ^ this.Multiply(c, 0x0d) ^ this.Multiply(d, 0x09);
state[i*4+1] = this.Multiply(a, 0x09) ^ this.Multiply(b, 0x0e) ^ this.Multiply(c, 0x0b) ^ this.Multiply(d, 0x0d);
state[i*4+2] = this.Multiply(a, 0x0d) ^ this.Multiply(b, 0x09) ^ this.Multiply(c, 0x0e) ^ this.Multiply(d, 0x0b);
state[i*4+3] = this.Multiply(a, 0x0b) ^ this.Multiply(b, 0x0d) ^ this.Multiply(c, 0x09) ^ this.Multiply(d, 0x0e) ;
  }
  return state
}
```

Everything else in the program is working fine but I don't understand `MixColumn` transformation so I can't debug this and I have no idea why it is producing bigger output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is here:

```
AES.prototype.xtime = function(x){ 
    return ((x << 1) ^ (((x >> 7) & 1) * 0x1b)) 
}
```

This code appears to assume that somehow the return value is being truncated 8 bits; I suspect that's not true for your implementation.

If you change this to:

```
AES.prototype.xtime = function(x){ 
    return (((x << 1) & 0xfe) ^ (((x >> 7) & 1) * 0x1b)) 
}
```

it might work as expected...